# Mongo find position by id in an Array of Objects

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a range of documents

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("5e388da4df54cb8efb47e61b"),
    userId:'test_user'
    productId:'product_6_id'
    recommendations:{
    _id:123
     rankedList:[
        0:{id:ObjectId('product_5_id'),Name:'Product_5'},
        1:{id:ObjectId('product_6_id'),Name:'Product_6'},
        2:{id:ObjectId('product_3_id'),Name:'Product_3'}],
    Date:'2020-02-25T05:03:55.439+00:00'
    }
    
},
{
    _id: ObjectId("5e388da4df54cb8efb47e62b"),
    userId:'test_user1'
    productId:'product_3_id'
    recommendations:{
    _id:123
     rankedList:[
        0:{id:ObjectId('product_1_id'),Name:'Product_1'},
        1:{id:ObjectId('product_5_id'),Name:'Product_5'},
        2:{id:ObjectId('product_3_id'),Name:'Product_3'}],
    Date:'2020-02-25T05:03:55.439+00:00'
    }
    
}
```

and I need to find each time the position of `productId` within the Array of objects `rankedList`.
Thus here the answer would be **positionIndex=1** for first doc and **positionIndex=2** for second document.
I am quite confused with `$indexOfArray` and how I should use it here with aggregate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need [$indexOfArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/). The tricky part is that `recommendations.rankedList` is an array of objects however MongoDB allows you to use following expression:

```
$recommendations.rankedList.id
```

which evaluates to a list of strings, `['product_5_id', 'product_6_id', 'product_3_id']` in this case so your code can look like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            index: {
                $indexOfArray: [ "$recommendations.rankedList.id", "$productId" ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6sG9ZWyrBUW)